# Free, easy, lightweight DLNA/UPnP servers for Linux

Tags: linux, gratis, dlna

On my Linux PC, I've stored many personal photos, videos, and, of course, music files. I have several devices capable of interacting with DLNA/UPnP servers to make use of that collection. So I'm looking for a DLNA/UPnP server software for Linux, which...

- is easy to setup, configure, and handle (management console would be nice)
- supports most common file formats (i.e. is not restricted to only a few)
- is "resource-friendly" (aka "light-weight")
- runs stable
- is not "cluttered"
- is freely available

Nice-to-haves:

- metadata retrieval from sources like IMDB etc. (for music and movies), adjustable in terms of an interface for own additions
- optional plus (not requirement): remote management console for Android
- a great plus would be if it can act as DLNA controller, so media can be *sent* to renderers (instead of only being looked up by them)

I've already tried several candidates, but ran into as many limitations as I've tried candidates: [miniDLNA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/) often got a "hick-up" (got stuck and ate resources), [Serviio](http://serviio.org/) is mostly a time-limited trial when it comes to its GUI. Several others were simply "too big" (e.g. [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/)).

What are your experiences? Which are the DLNA servers matching above specifications *you* would recommend, based on *your own experience*, and *why* would you recommend them?

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at [Media Tomb](http://mediatomb.cc/), which is a free, open source and highly configurable UPnP media server for Linux supporting the following features and more:

- It has a web user interface for management
- Supports a plethora of media types and supports plugins
- Is freely available (licensed under GNU)
- Supports metadata extraction from MP3, OGG, FLAC, JPEG, etc

The web front end is easy to use and looks like this (the filenames are blurred on purpose!):

[image: Media Tomb UI]

From here you can add files, folders, set auto re-scanning preferences and more.

Comment: Thanks, Flyk! In fact, I already had MediaTomb on my list. Don't remember why I skipped it back then. Will take a look at it again.

Comment: From the website: "MediaTomb version 0.11.0 introduces a new feature - transcoding (...) Last but not least - subtitles". Been looking for something like that for *months*. I am **so much** testing it now!