# good dlna media server for xbox 360 on debian

Tags: linux, media-player, media-manager, dlna

What are some compatible media servers with xbox 360 that can also do on the fly trans coding that are available on Debian and won't give choppy playback like plex has?

Comment: Related: [Free, easy, lightweight DLNA/UPnP servers for Linux](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/402/185)